# JS chart to display values in php table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I would like to display the values of my php table in this javascript chart. The script values for var d1 d2 and d3 is just dummy/demo. I'd like to have the month run along the x axis. I just dont know how to go about merging my php with js.

My Table (PHP)

```
<?php                           if ($bymonths = $db->get_results("SELECT * from vw_dash_bymonth_2012"));
                        foreach ($bymonths as $month) {
                            $startmonth = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('first day of this month', $month->realdate));
                            $endmonth = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('last day of this month', $month->realdate));
                            echo "<tr>
                            <td><a href=bymonth.php?month={$month->month1}>" . date('F', $month->realdate) . "</a> " . date('Y', $month->realdate) . "</td>
                            <td>" . $month->gallons . "</td>
                            <td>" . $month->service . "</td>
                            <td>" . $month->average . "</td></tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
```

Sample JS

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    var d1 = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5)
                        d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);

                    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

                    var d3 = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5)
                        d3.push([i, Math.cos(i)]);

                    $.plot($("#multiple"), [
                        {
                            label: "Gallons",
                            data: d1,
                            lines: { show: true },
                            points: { show: true, fill: true }
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Services",
                            data: d2,
                            lines: { show: true },
                            points: { show: true, fill: true }
                        },
                        {
                            label: "Average",
                            data: d3,
                            lines: { show: true },
                            points: { show: true, fill: true }
                        }
                    ]);
                });
                </script>
```

Comment: Why not make an AJAX call from your javascript to the php file and return your variables in JSON format. Then they can be used in your javascript.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/2892070/using-jquerys-ajax-get-request-with-parameters-returning-page-content